# MATLAB Code for triple integral

Tags: integration, matlab, programming

I want to evaluate the $\int\int\int dxdydz$ using 'integral3' function in MATLAB. But the only code my intuition has helped me it this:

```
g = @(x,y,z) 1
u = integral3(g,1,2,1,3,1,4)
```

But this results in errors. Please help me create the correct code.

Comment: what kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`integral3` expects the function `g` to be vectorized, however, `g = @(x,y,z) 1` will always return a scalar, no matter the dimensions of the input `x`, `y`, or `z`.

A simple fix:

```
g = @(x,y,z) 1 + 0*x
u = integral3(g,1,2,1,3,1,4)
```

Another example

```
g = @(x,y,z) x.*y
u = integral3(g,1,2,1,3,1,4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, It worked!

Answer (score -2):

```
clear all
clc
syms x y z
xa=-2;
xb=2;
ya=-sqrt(2-x^2/2);
yb=sqrt(2-x^2/2);
za=x^2+3*y^2;
zb=8-x^2-y^2;
I=int(int(int(1+0*z,z,za,zb),y,ya,yb),x,xa,xb)
viewSolid(z,za,zb,y,ya,yb,x,xa,xb)
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Right now, your answer is unreadable. I suggest you learn to format your answers with MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference